# Public IP, access from router to modem

Tags: ip, nat

I have a network structure based in the following way:

```
    PC ------------ ROUTER ------------ MODEM ------------ INTERNET
```

I´ve set up a public ip in modem, and I need to access it from the PC, how can I do that?

Comment: Can you update with what exactly you are trying to do? Are you trying to host a resource from the PC and access it via the public IP externally?

Comment: Accessing the web server public IP from your private network will only work if your router supports [NAT Reflection/NAT Loopback/NAT Hairpinning? - NYC Networkers](https://web.archive.org/web/20181017232841/https://www.nycnetworkers.com/real-world/nat-reflectionnat-loopbacknat-hairpinning/). Most consumer grade routers don't.

Comment: Are you sure that you are allowed to set the public IP of your network? In most cases the IP of your modem would be set by your provider via [RADIUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RADIUS) or [DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol).

Comment: I have an web application already working locally with a local-host access, but now I want allow that anyone outside my private network access to my application. I need an external IP to allow that. The modem I´m using is Technicolor TD5136v2